# Application of Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, cauchy-problem

Let $f(z)$ be analytic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$, where $f'(z_0)$ does not equal $0$. Show that

$$\int_C\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{f(z)-f(z_0)} = \frac{2\pi i}{f'(z_0)}$$

where $C$ is a small (as small as necessary) circle centred at $z_0$.

I think the question probably involves setting $g(z)$ to some function like
$\frac{z - z_0}{f(z)-f(z_0)}$, however I can't use this properly to find an answer.

Comment: Duplicate targets found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B2%5Cpi%20i%7D%7Bf%27(z_0)%7D%3D%5Coint_%5Cgamma%20%5Cfrac%7Bdz%7D%7Bf(z)%20-%20f(z_0)%7D%24)

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem somewhat screams Residue theorem. In particular, if we make $C$ sufficiently small, $z\mapsto\frac{1}{f(z)-f(z_0)}$ is holomorphic on the disk bounded by $C$ except for at $z_0$, and so by the Residue theorem

$$\int_C\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{f(z)-f(z_0)}=2\pi i\mathop{\operatorname{Res}}_{z=z_0}\frac{1}{f(z)-f(z_0)}.$$

Now it is easy to check that the pole at $z_0$ is simple (this follows from the condition that $f'(z_0)\neq0$), and so

$$\mathop{\operatorname{Res}}_{z=z_0}\frac{1}{f(z)-f(z_0)}=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{z-z_0}{f(z)-f(z_0)}=\frac{1}{f'(z_0)}.$$

Combining the above we get the result.

Comment: It also screams “duplicate!” :)